# Android how to intercept chat messages (BBM, Viber, Skype, WhatsApp and the like )

Tags: android

Thanks for your help.

I have been asked do build a child monitoring App,

which should be able to intercept IM messaging: BBM, Viber, Skype, WhatsApp and the like.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes with root but I would have no clue how but your best bet is to take screen shots of the screen like every 5 minutes or so with like a background service launched on the device.  You also can't intercept the messages because of encryption.

Comment: what reason from screenshots if app is closed?